# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n)\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}f(m,n)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

Let $f(m,n)$  be a double sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n)$ is absolutely convergent and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(m,n)$ converges.

> Question: Prove that assuming the sums and limits and their combination below are all convergent$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n)\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}f(m,n)\right)$$
> **Edit** What are the extra mild assumptions so that the above inequality is true?

I tried using Fatou's lemma but the sequence $f(m,n)$ is not non negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider

\begin{equation}
f(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{n} &\text{ if } n\leq m<2n\\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n) = -1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(m,n) = 0$ which turns your inequality into

\begin{equation}
-1\geq 0.
\end{equation}

This function is an example of why non-negativity is an essential requirement of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: But your $\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m,n) $ is not absolutely convergent. Is it?

Comment: @Curious It is absolutely convergent because $\sum_{m=1}^\infty |f(m,n)| = 1 <\infty$.

Comment: How is that sum equal to $1$?

Comment: @Curious Because $n/n=1$ I guess.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Thanks. I got it. So what extra mild assumptions can we take so that the statement is true?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. I got it. So what extra mild assumptions can we take so that the statement is true?

Comment: @Curious Non-negativity of $f$. Else you are just proving a stronger version of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @Curious Have a look at [Extensions and variations of Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Extensions_and_variations_of_Fatou's_lemma).

Comment: @Andreas I am happy to give your answer a check mark. Where can I find the extension of Fatou's lemma. Any reference of a book?

Comment: @Curious Sorry, no, I just looked at Wikipedia. Maybe try the references under that article.